# Авторизация вконтакте

Tags: авторизация, вконтакте

Как реализовать считывание данных с аккаунта ВК, используя ID вк-юзера, вида:
`http://vk.com/id*******`; 
а также статус данного пользователя (т.е. проверяется id + статус, а после идет считывание некоторой информации данного пользователя). При этом пользователю (вконтакте) не обязательно авторизовываться, данные должны считываться без логина.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый же клик по [документации](http://vk.com/dev/methods) обнаруживает что-то очень непонятное:

- [users.get](http://vk.com/dev/users.get). Возвращает расширенную
     информацию о пользователях. Это
     открытый метод, не требующий
     access_token.